# Deserialize XML starting with child element using Jackson

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson

I am attempting to parse some XML using Jackson. However, I can't figure out how to start with the  element when parsing. This API call will never return more than one :

```
<return_data api_call="get">
<users>
<user>
<username>jdoe</username>
<firstname>John</firstname>
<lastname>Doe</lastname>
<account_expiration_date>0000-00-00</account_expiration_date>
<signup_date>2015-01-01 15:00:36</signup_date>
<deleted>0</deleted>
<account_name>my account</account_name>
</user>
</users>
</return_data>
```

I tried the following, but am getting the error 'Unrecognized field "users"... not marked as ignorable'.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "user")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "api_call" })
public class User {

@JsonProperty("username")
private String userName;

@JsonProperty("firstname")
private String firstName;

@JsonProperty("lastname")
private String lastName;

@JsonProperty("account_expiration_date")
private Date expirationDate;

@JsonProperty("deleted")
private boolean deleted;

@JsonProperty("signup_date")
private Date signupDate;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Date getExpirationDate() {
    return expirationDate;
}

public void setExpirationDate(Date expirationDate) {
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
}

public Date getSignupDate() {
    return signupDate;
}

public void setSignupDate(Date signupDate) {
    this.signupDate = signupDate;
}
}
```

Update:
I was able to get it working by using multiple wrappers, but I'm hoping there is an easier solution.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "api_call" })
public class ReturnDataWrapper {

@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "users")
@JsonProperty("users")
private UserWrapper userWrapper;

public UserWrapper getUserWrapper() {
    return userWrapper;
}

public void setUserWrapper(UserWrapper userWrapper) {
    this.userWrapper = userWrapper;
}
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "users")
@JsonRootName("users")
public class AlertAccountWrapper {

@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "user")
@JsonProperty("user")
public User account;

public User getUser() {
    return account;
}

public void setUser(User account) {
    this.account = account;
}

}
```

I also removed @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "user") and @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "api_call" }) from the User class.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to debug this would be to try the reverse: create object you think should match, serialize it as XML, see how it differs from what you expect.
This should give you a hint at where discrepancy lies.